# memory allocation for global symbols defined at multiple places in C

Tags: c, global-variables

For global defintions that share the same name, do we allocate the memory for each of them?
Will linkers affect how we allocate memory for these global symbols?

The following is what I thought the possible ways of resolving this:

1.We first allocate the memory for global variables as we encounter them in the program.  (Every definition will have the memory.)  Then linkers resolve the global symbols.

2.After linkers resolve global symbols with same name defined at multiple places, we only allocate the memory for one definition.

Does one of them correct?

Example:

b.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.c"
void f(void);
int x = 15213;
int main()
{
  f();
  printf("x = %d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

a.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x;
void f()
{
  printf("x in f = %d\n", x);
  x = 15212;
}
```

The above code compiled and ran without any errors or warnings.
This is what I get:

```
x in f = 0
x = 15212
```

Do we have one x defintion in the memory or two?

One quick question related to this:

Global and static variables are stored in the Data segment(DS) when initialized and block start by symbol (BSS) when uninitialized.  Even though data in BSS are unintialized, they will always be set to the default value instead of garbage value.  Is this right?

Comment: If you have multiple definition for a global and none of them are marked as weak, the linker will fail. You cannot have two definitions with the same name in `C`.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya, I mean the case when we have one weak and one strong or both weak.  If we don't have extern keyword, "int x;" is a defintion but it's weak since it doesn't have an initialization.

Comment: No, `int x;` without extern and without initialization is not a weak definition. It is actually the same just initialized to zero in this case.

Comment: "weak" is not mentioned in C standard and should be toolchain-defined. for example ARMCC and IAR uses keyword "__weak" and GCC uses "__attribute__((weak))".

Comment: It is extern by default.

Comment: @purec, doesn't variable extern explicitly and function extern implicitly? Therefore, if we have "int x;", it's a defintion.  We allocate the memory for x and give a garbage value to it.  If we have "extern int x;", we only have a declaration of x and no memory is assigned to it.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya, I don't know if this source is reliable.  Uninitialized global variables get weak symbols from (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-linkers-resolve-multiply-defined-global-symbols/) The code I posted above actually compiled and ran without any warnings.  Does it mean they are not both strong defintions?

Comment: @Xavier Yin, thanks for your reply.  Do you know where we can check the definition of weak and strong linkage?

Comment: Compiler regards "int x;" as declaration in this case. I personally always use extern keyword.

Comment: You can print address if you want.

Comment: @LushaLi this is a non standard behavior from `gcc`. Actually C doesn't even have the notion of weak symbols. According to the standard, you are not allowed to define the same global variable twice. Even if it is across modules. Multiple declarations are okay. I think `gcc` is providing this extension in case programmer forget to write `extern`. This also means you shouldn't rely on this behavior. Because other compilers won't.

Comment: @purec, I double checked another book (which should be reliable). "int x;" declares and defines but "extern int x;" only declares.  Here, two x share the same address because of linkage.

Comment: We should continue in the chat if you want. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173873/memory-allocation-for-global-symbols-defined-at-multiple-places-in-c

Comment: It is called tentative definition. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Tentative_Definitions

Answer (score 0):

If each of the two .c files declares its own global int x as your example, two different variables in memory are allocated.

Note that they live in different scope so the symbols are not accessed from the other file. That is, each file always access its own int x by the global variable name "x".

Your compiler should complain if you attempt to **extern** a global variable to any source file where a global variable with the same name exists.

Answer (score 0):

Since one of the C files is directly `#include`-d in the other, they are in the same translation unit.  (This, by the way, is not recommended—programmers are used to header files being named `*.h`, not `*.c`, and to `*.c` files being compiled on their own.)  As far as the compiler is concerned, the programmer just copied-and-pasted the contents of one file into the other.  There is a forward declaration of `x`, but only a single definition.

If you put the `extern` declaration into a separate translation unit and compiled them into separate object files, only the one containing the definition `int x = 15213;` would allocate memory, not the one containing the declaration `int x;`.  Writing `extern int x;` might make it easier to remember that `x` is defined elsewhere.  If you write two definitions of `x` and attempt to link them, the linker will give you an error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am asking a different question.

Comment: @LushaLi Is that more what you wanted to know?